# Importing CSV Data to Realm Results in "null" String Instead of Swift nil for Optional String

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am importing data from a CSV file into a local Realm database. One of the properties in my Realm model is a String that's defined as optional (String?).

When I encounter a CSV field with an empty value (i.e., ,,), upon importing it into Realm, it displays as *null* in Realm Studio. Not a "null" String. However, in Swift, when I retrieve this property, it returns "null" as a String instead of nil. The property is optional in my Swift class.

```
@objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
```

Is there a way to handle empty CSV values such that they're imported into Realm as actual nil values in Swift? I want to ensure that the optional String property is correctly represented as nil in my Swift code?

Comment: I posted an answer showing that importing nothing into an optional field results in a nil value as it should. If you are seeing a different behavior, please provide more info in the question so we can duplicate it - perhaps some sample data and then a screenshot of what you see in Realm Studio and then the code to read that in showing that the null showing in Realm Studio is being read in as something other than nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm Studio shows nil values as "null" where properties contain nil, as in an optional with no value.

Here's an example. Create a Test modal with two properties, a non optional and an optional

```
class Test: Object {
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var myOptional: String?
}
```

Then some code to test what was imported

```
let results = realm.objects(Test.self)

for r in results {
    print( type(of: r.myOptional) )
    if r.myOptional == nil {
        print("myOptional was nil")
    } else {
        print("myOptional was not nil")
    }
}
```

The above code reads in all of the imported values, gets the type object `myOptional` is and prints it to console and then determines if it was nil or not.

Here's the flatfile containing two objects to import called Test.csv. Note that the optional property for the Jay object is "some string" and the optional property for Cindy is empty

```
name,myOptional
Jay,some string
Cindy,
```

Then import the flat file which looks like this in Realm Studio

[image]

run the code and here's the console output

```
The myOptional property was of type: Optional<String>
    myOptional was not nil
The myOptional property was of type: Optional<String>
    myOptional was nil
```

**EDIT:**

Question about handling double quotes in the header and data fields. Here's an example

```
"name","myOptional"
Jay,some string
Cindy,
"Hello","World"
"Hello",
```

and when importing, the result

[image]

Comment: I followed your guide to create sample data and realised the problem comes when my header line in csv has double quotes ie. "id","name".... Must have to do with Realm Studio i guess

Comment: @Zack Realm Studio should handle double quotes in both the header as well as the data fields. See my Edit